# Can't install Java in Vista because of an Error 1603

Tags: windows, installation, windows-vista, java

**Background**

I have had the same laptop for about 6 years (an Acer Aspire 8920), which runs Windows Vista. I have 2 hard drives, and I use one for the OS, and one for larger applications and data. Periodically I re-install Windows (and then all the applications) to keep things running nicely. Everything has always been fine, until now:

**The problem**

I just cannot install Java. I have installed it before, on this laptop and on other PCs, and never had a problem with it.

**To recreate the problem**

- Format HD
- Install Windows Vista
- Try to install Java 7 or 8 (offline versions)
- Install gets almost to the end, then throws a 1603 error.

**What have I tried so far**

- Using the online and offline installer
- Turning off User Account Control
- Using PDQ Deploy, and deploying the Java 7 (32-bit) and ALTERNATIVE versions.
- Checking that I am logged in as Administrator.
- Right click on the installer and "Run as Administrator"
- Checking that my HDs are not encrypted
- Checking that my HDs are not substitute drives
- Installing to C:\Java
- Installing to D:\Java

**Additional Information**
Two other strange symptoms might be relevant.

- Windows is sometimes not letting me execute downloaded files. In those cases, if I copy them onto a memory stick, and unplug/replug the stick, then I can run from the stick.
- I installed another application, PSoC Creator, which in an IDE for a microcontroller, and I've had it working on this laptop before. It contains GCC, however when I try to compile code using the IDE, GCC fails with the message: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory. Again, nothing I do seems to fix this.

Comment: [Error 1603: Java Update did not complete.](https://java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml)

Comment: [Beat the Java Error 1603 When Deploying](http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/beat-java-error-1603-when-deploying)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thanks for the links. I have seen them already. They mostly pertain to removing old versions of Java, and as you can see, I'm trying to install on a fresh install of Windows. They also mention trying the offline installer, which I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that under Vista, Java needs SP1 installed.

I was naively installing a fresh copy of Vista, thinking that something else was interferring with it, whereas the fresh Vista was itself the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your environment variables search for entry for `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and remove it